# Getting unique results with elasticsearch acorrding to field

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I'm using **FOSElasticaBundle** with **Symfony2** on my project and there are entry and user tables on MySQL database and each entry belongs to one user.

I want to get just one entry per a user among the whole entries from the database.

**Entries Representation**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hello world",
    "user": {
      "id": 17,
      "username": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Lorem ipsum",
    "user": {
      "id": 15,
      "username": "bar"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Dolar sit amet",
    "user": {
      "id": 17,
      "username": "foo"
    }
  },
]
```

Expected result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hello world",
    "user": {
      "id": 17,
      "username": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Lorem ipsum",
    "user": {
      "id": 15,
      "username": "bar"
    }
  }
]
```

But it returns all entries on table. I've tried to add an aggregation to my elasticsearch query and nothing changed.

```
$distinctAgg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms("distinctAgg");
$distinctAgg->setField("user.id");
$distinctAgg->setSize(1);

$query->addAggregation($distinctAgg);
```

Is there any way to do this via term filter or anything else? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregations are not easy to understand when you are used to MySQL group by.

**The first thing**, is that aggregations results are not returned in `hits`, but in `aggregations`. So when you get the result of your search, you have to get aggregations like that :

```
$results = $search->search();
$aggregationsResults = $results->getAggregations();
```

**The second thing** is that aggregations wont return you the source. With the aggregation of your example, you will only know that you have 1 user with ID 15, and 2 users with ID 15.

E.g. with this query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byUser": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [ ... ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "byUser": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 17,
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": 15,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to get results, the same way you would do with a GROUP BY in MySQL, you have to use a `top_hits` sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byUser": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "results": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [ ... ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "byUser": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 17,
               "doc_count": 2,
               "results": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 2,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "test_stackoverflow",
                           "_type": "test1",
                           "_id": "1",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "id": 1,
                              "name": "Hello world",
                              "user": {
                                 "id": 17,
                                 "username": "foo"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": 15,
               "doc_count": 1,
               "results": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "test_stackoverflow",
                           "_type": "test1",
                           "_id": "2",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "id": 2,
                              "name": "Lorem ipsum",
                              "user": {
                                 "id": 15,
                                 "username": "bar"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

More informations on this page : https://www.elastic.co/blog/top-hits-aggregation